# Recursion in EF seems to not initialise the context at all

Tags: c#, entity-framework, recursion, dbcontext

For some reason this "small-ish" example doesn't seem to work on my pc, am I doing something wrong?

```
public class ResourceSection
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentSection")]
    public int? ParentSectionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get { return ParentSectionId != null ? ParentSection.Path + "." + Name : Name; } }
    public virtual ResourceSection ParentSection { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ResourceSection> ChildSections { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ResourceString> Resources { get; set; }
}

public class ResourceString
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Section")]
    public int SectionId { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string Culture { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ShortDisplayName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ResourceSection Section { get; set; }
}

public class ResourcesContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ResourceSection> Sections { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ResourceString> Resources { get; set; }
}

public class ResourcingTests
{
    public void TestResourceContextInit()
    {
        // init the db
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ResourcesContext, Configuration>());

        // build the context
        var foo = new ResourcesContext();

        // do some sort of query on it
        var sections = foo.Sections.Where(s => s.Id > 0).ToList();

        // jobs a good un right? ... right?
        Console.WriteLine("Resources initialised");
    }
}
```

... I get "Resources initialised" out on the console but my understanding is that this should create my db too. 
The connection string is definitely correct and i simply have an empty configuration class for the migrations stuff which has added "AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;" in to the ctor, I have also scripted an initial migration by using "add-migration Initial" in the package manager console which correctly creates a working migration.

I can test that all this works by calling "update-database" and see that it generates the correct db.

So why isn't it "automatically" creating my db like all my other contexts do?

Side note:

This is an extract of the code removed from a much larger web project in to a console app, normally I use msdeploy to roll out new db's by simply deploying the code but this appears to cause IIS to simply freeze when processing the first request.

EDIT: The missing bits ...

Here's the migration that gets generated:

```
public partial class Initial : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.ResourceStrings",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    SectionId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Culture = c.String(nullable: false),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false),
                    DisplayName = c.String(nullable: false),
                    ShortDisplayName = c.String(nullable: false),
                    Description = c.String(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.ResourceSections", t => t.SectionId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.SectionId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.ResourceSections",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    ParentSectionId = c.Int(),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.ResourceSections", t => t.ParentSectionId)
            .Index(t => t.ParentSectionId);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.ResourceStrings", "SectionId", "dbo.ResourceSections");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.ResourceSections", "ParentSectionId", "dbo.ResourceSections");
        DropIndex("dbo.ResourceSections", new[] { "ParentSectionId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.ResourceStrings", new[] { "SectionId" });
        DropTable("dbo.ResourceSections");
        DropTable("dbo.ResourceStrings");
    }
}
```

... and here's my configuration class (also generated by EF / Microsoft when enabling migrations on the app) ...

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Tests.ResourcesContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Tests.ResourcesContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

... as I said above if I use the "update-database" command from the package manager console it all works perfectly, I can't seem to run the code and have it generate the db on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the code from your question worked correctly for me, so it would suggest something wrong with the bits you haven't shown us.  Additionally, the code cannot get to "Resources initialised" without calling out to a created context, so that would suggest a possible problem with your connection strings.

I would start by calling this with a breakpoint, examining the `foo` object, specifically checking the connection string of the created database.  Perhaps it's been created somewhere you didn't notice, like on a localdb connection?  If so, then maybe it used the automatic connection string rather than the one you expected.

Comment: Yeh that was my suspicion before asking. My web stack has like 10 other db's and all the connection strings are identical except for the db name so I can't see how that would break it ... well at least it's just something local to my machine ... stand by while I hit it with the debugger

Comment: oh that's odd ... if i actually add a section ot the db and call savechanges before doing the select query it creates the db ... how peculiar!

Comment: oh well, thx for the help ... it seems the code isn't broken at all :s